# Lua coroutines, cannot resume dead coroutine

Tags: lua, iterator, coroutine

First things first the code I am working on is not my code but an old code that has been abandoned that I am trying to fix up. It's a short script which is supposed to read a text file and output an ASCII image, wait a short period then show another ASCII image creating a kind of ASCII movie or slideshow. I am not too familiar with Lua and have run into the problem where the code outputs "cannot resume dead coroutine". However it seems to continually say this as if it is still stuck in an infinite loop. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
local component = require("component")
local term = require("term")
local filesystem = require("filesystem")
local gpu = component.gpu

local moviefile = "/usr/movies/1.txt"
local f = filesystem.open(moviefile, "rb")
local filmText = f:read(filesystem.size(moviefile))
f:close()

local function iterator()
    return coroutine.wrap( function()
        for line in string.gmatch( filmText, "([^\n]*)\n") do
            coroutine.yield(line)
        end
        return false
    end )
end

term.clear()
local it = iterator()

local bFinished = false
while not bFinished do
    -- Read the frame header
    local holdLine = it()
    if not holdLine then
        bFinished = true
        break
    end

    -- Get this every frame incase the monitor resizes  
    local w,h = gpu.getResolution()
    local startX = math.floor( (w - 65) / 2 )
    local startY = math.floor( (h - 14) / 2 )

    -- Print the frame
    term.clear()
    for n=1,13 do
        local line = it()
        if line then
            term.setCursor(startX, startY + n)
            term.write( line )
        else
            bFinished = true
            break
        end
    end

    -- Hold the frame
    local hold = tonumber(holdLine) or 1
    local delay = (hold * 0.05) - 0.01
    os.sleep( delay )
end
```

Comment: This program is correct, it should work.

Comment: Is there anything unique about the environment the script is run in?